# DeflateInputStream and InflateOutputStream

Tags: java

We usually compress data with `DeflateOutputStream` (or `GZIPOutputStream`) and decompress them with `InflateInputStream` (or `GZIPInputStream`).

But we have `DeflateInputStream` and `InflateOutputStream` since Java 1.6. What are the usages of these two classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use them if you need to process data in its compressed (deflated) format, or if you have compressed data in memory that you need to decompress and output. This could come in handy if you need to store compressed data in some location that does not handle streams very well (such as a database field), or if you have obtained compressed data from a non-stream source and want to decompress it to a stream destination.

Comment: if I need a compressed data, `DeflateOutputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` can also do that.